# Spring MVC 3 JSON serializer returning backing fields and ignoring encapsulation

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, encapsulation

I have a controller returning JSON:

```
public @ResponseBody ResourcesModel data(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id, @PathVariable(value = "page") int page){
     //populate model
}
```

Here is the relevant portion of the model:

```
public class ResourcesModel {
    private boolean showLeft;       

    public boolean getShowLeft(){
        return getPage() > 1;
    }

    public void setShowLeft(boolean b) { /*doesn't do anything*/  }
}
```

Without the backing field, showLeft does not get serialized. During serialization, it just looks at the field and ignores the getter. I find this very annoying... what is the point of encapsulation if it is ignored?

I know there are work arounds like setting showLeft in the controller, but I'd like to avoid this and use proper OO. Any suggestions to give the serializer hints?

Answer (score 0):

I think that Just you have to add @JsonSetter to the field showLeft annotation

```
public class ResourcesModel {
    private boolean showLeft;       

    public boolean getShowLeft(){
        return getPage() > 1;
    }
    @JsonSetter
    public void setShowLeft(boolean b) { /*doesn't do anything*/  }
}
```